# C# infer Type from Generic with constraint

Tags: c#, events, generics, types, type-inference

I'm trying to register a generic that derives from a base class in the following way, but getting the error :

> cannot convert `MyCallback<T>` expression to type `MyCallback<Event>`

I was hoping the constraints would make this possible but am I missing something?

```
public class Event
{ };

public delegate void MyCallback<T>(T arg1) where T : Event;

static class EventDispatcher
{

    public static Dictionary<string, MyCallback<Event>> eventTable = new Dictionary<string, MyCallback<Event>>();

    static void RegisterCallback<T>(MyCallback<T> callback) where T : Event
    {
        eventTable.Add("test", callback);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you use generics here at all? Should work with plain polymorphism when using .NET 3.5 or higher.

Comment: Mainly to enforce correct type registration and allow more specific delegate handling. I want to programmitcally constrain that the caller of RegisterCallback<T> is expecting an object of type T in their eventual callback delegate. This will allow me to do something like RegisterCallback<ThisOddType>(MyFunction), where MyFunction(ThisOddType objectIKnowAbout)

Comment: @user3130210 How do you plan to ensure that the callbacks are called with the proper arguments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a `MyCallback<Event>` you're saying that you have a method that can take *any* type of event.  It can accept an `EventOne`, or an `EventTwo`, or a `SomeOtherEvent`.

Let's say I call `RegisterCallback` and pass in a delegate pointing to a method with this signature:

```
public static void Foo(SomeOtherEvent arg)
```

If your code would work, and I could assign that to a `MyCallback<Event>`, then I could pass in an `EventOne` instance to that method when calling it.  That's obviously a problem.

There's a term for that; you're expecting `MyCallback` to be *covariant* with respect to it's generic argument.  In fact, it's *contravariant*.  If I have a method that can accept *any* type of event, I can clearly pass in a `SomeEvent`, or a `SomeOtherEvent`, meaning I could assign a `MyCallback<Event>` to a `MyCallback<SomeOtherEvent>`, rather than the other way around.

If you want to tell the compiler that, "I know that this method cannot actually be called with any type of event, but I want you to allow this check and only fail at runtime if the given argument is not of the proper type." then you *can* do that, assuming you actually have a way of ensuring you call each callback with the proper arguments.  You can't just do a cast either; you need to wrap the method in a new method that does the cast:

```
eventTable.Add("test", e => callback((T)e));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the type parameter be part of the `EventDispatcher` class:

```
public class EventDispatcher<T> : where T : Event {
  public Dictionary<string, MyCallback<T>> eventTable = new Dictionary<string, MyCallback<T>>();

  void RegisterCallback(MyCallback<T> callback) {
    eventTable.Add("test", callback);
  }
}
```

This is because the `MyCallback<Event>` declared in `eventTable` is not going to be compiled into the same type declared in `RegisteredCallback` when written like your example.

Comment: I want to be able to register separately typed events into the same dictionary, so it could hold EventT1 and EventT2 both of which derive from Event. Doing this would constrain me to only ever register events with this dictionary of a single type?

Comment: correct, inheritance does not normally carry through to type parameters. Some interfaces like `IEnumerable<T>` support covariance and/or contravariance. The `Dictionary<T,U>` type does not.

Comment: @CharlesLambert He's not trying to rely on the covariance of  `Dictionary` here, but rather of `MyCallback`.  Of course, it, by design, cannot be covariant.  It could be (although currently is not) made to be contravariant.